# Caching a JSON result in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have the following controller that returns a list of tags when it receives an HTTP request to /tags

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :index

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        render :json => Tag.all(:order => "name").to_json
      }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm noticing that whenever a request is made to /tags, Rails is generating a cache file at /public/tags.json. However, it never seems to use this cache file. Instead, it always runs the SQL query to retrieve the tags:

```
Started GET "/tags" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-15 08:27:29 -0700
  Processing by TagsController#index as JSON
  Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY name
Write page <project root path>/public/tags.json (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Why isn't Rails using the cache file that's being generated? Is it because the request is for /tags and not /tags.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are probably correct, you can specify the `:cache_path` option to tell it what to name the file so do

```
caches_page :index, :cache_path => '' # if not try 'tags'
```

you can also pass a proc, if you want to include params

```
caches_page :index , :cache_path => Proc.new {|controller| controller.params }
```

or anything else

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it's still exhibiting the same behavior (saving to /public/tags.json).

Comment: well the way page caching works it just generates static pages, in public, which are grabbed by the web server without ever touching rails. So you wither have to get rails to save them with a different name, or get your webserver ( Apache or whatever ) to have an alias to that file. Or make the client request the page with extension. At least i think something like  that should work

Comment: if it only replies in json, take out the respond_to block, thatis what is appending the .json  possibly

Comment: but to use this, we need to install `actionpack-page_caching` gem, isn't there a way to do this in `core` itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your cache directory could be in the wrong place.  I had this issue before where I was trying to place the cache in a directory other than public.